# Magento 1: Showing templateControl is not defined message in console

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

In transactional emails, I am trying to call custom value and attributes but my changes are not reflecting on a email.

I tried to look a using email template but my email template also is not working properly.

It shows an error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: templateControl is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):560)".

[image]

I am struggling for this issue since one month, don't know why my changes are not reflected on transactional emails and why admin showing this error in console.

What can be the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: dropdown in any email template showing?

Comment: NO, it shows empty and it stuck

Comment: then problem in third party extension

Comment: We have added CED commerce marketplace extension for vendors and GST.

Comment: you cant try this extension disable and after check it

Comment: Thanks Rakesh,  I'll try it